# I want to get the data from multiple Tables by Using Query in Kotlin with Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kotlin

```
@Query("select product.name,samp.cname,samp.price from product INNER JOIN
        samp ON product.id=samp.product_id", nativeQuery = true)
fun getdata(@Param("name") name:String,@Param("cname") cname:String,
            @Param("price") price:Integer): List<product>
```

I wrote a query like this but I did not get the data and its shows an internal server error in Postman. IntelliJ shows parameter `productrepository.getdata()` must not be null!..

Comment: can you please provide the full error that is being logged in Intellij as well as the code that is calling `getdata`? By the look of what you've written, it seems like you're trying to pass a null value as an argument.

Comment: check if product id is true. for example if you pass 2 as product id but real product id is 1, it says it must not be null

Comment: Parameter name in productRepository.getdata must not be null! this is trhe error i got in intellij